# MapReduce set input and output

Tags: java, windows, mapreduce

I have a file

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.*;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.*;

public class ViewCount extends Configured implements Tool {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        int res = ToolRunner.run(new ViewCount(), args);
        System.exit(res);
    }

    public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
        //Path inputPath = new Path(args[0]);
        Path inputPath = Paths.get("C:/WorkSpace/input.txt");

        Path outputPath = Paths.get("C:/WorkSpace/output.txt");

        Configuration conf = getConf();
        Job job = new Job(conf, this.getClass().toString());
```

I try to run a the app in windows. How can I set **inputPath** and **outputPath**? The method I use now doesn't work. Before I had

```
Path inputPath = new Path(args[0]);
Path outputPath = new Path(args[1]);
```

and I had to go to the command line. Now I want to run the app from the IDE.

I'm getting

```
Required:
org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path
Found:
java.nio.file.Path
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Eclipse, you could set arguments :

Run -> run configuration -> arguments.

It should be the same in Intellij.

Comment: Should I separate them somehow? C:\WorkSpace\input.txt, C:\WorkSpace\output.txt

Comment: I get this error now `java.io.IOException: Cannot initialize Cluster. Please check your configuration for mapreduce.framework.name and the correspond server addresses`

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you that it is expecting a `org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path`, but instead it receives a `java.nio.file.Paths`.

This means that you should change the second import of your code to 
`org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path`. IDEs import suggestions can be wrong some times ;)

Change the import and then use the method that you already had to add the input and output path. Those arguments are given in Eclipse with right-clicking the project -> Run as -> Run configurations -> arguments. The two paths should be white-space separated. Apply and run!

For the next executions, just run the project.